# Layer is not valid error when connecting QGIS to PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgadmin-4

I am new to QGIS.
I am trying to connect a view from PostGIS to QGIS (3.16.4, same with 3.12).
The PostGIS connection in QGIS browser have no issues and when "Test Connection" it says it can connect.

But when I am  trying to add the layer I am getting this error:

> Layer is not valid: The layer dbname='dwa' host=localhost port=40802 user='user' password='user' key='"bin"' srid=4326 type=Polygon table="public"."height_grid_layer_view" (bin) is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map. Reason:

The pgAdmin 4 shows the view in Geometry Viewer without any problem with the SQL:
`SELECT * FROM public.height_grid_layer_view`

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Does your view have a primary key `id`?

Comment: looks like your table is a binary (bin) type - for QGIS needs to be a (geom)

Comment: In client/server operations the directionality is important. You want to connect **from** QGIS (client)  **to** PostgreSQL (database server). PostGIS is an EXTENSION within PostgreSQL, but there is a native PG geometry type as well, so your issue seems to be that you are *not* using PostGIS.

Comment: what do you get when you run `\d public.height_grid_layer_view` in the psql console (not in pgadmin)?

Comment: @JGH response from psql console:

`dwa-# \d public.height_grid_layer_view
ERROR:  column c.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: ...riggers, c.relrowsecurity, c.relforcerowsecurity, c.relhasoi...
                                                             ^
dwa-#`

Comment: @Mapperz  I am using PostGIS geometry

Comment: @Vince   I am not sure where to check/change directionality

Comment: @s.k I added the screen shot to my original post to show how it looks in PgAdmin

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461178/how-to-fix-error-column-c-relhasoids-does-not-exist-in-postgres/58462270#58462270).

Comment: @JGH I think you meant \dv as this is the view I am trying to access:
`dwa-# \dv public.height_grid_layer_view
                 List of relations
 Schema |          Name          | Type |  Owner
--------+------------------------+------+----------
 public | height_grid_layer_view | view | postgres
(1 row)


dwa-#`

Comment: You need a primary key, generate one if you don't have it.

Comment: nope. `\d` was intended.  Anyways, S.K comment is the solution to your problem

Comment: @s.k , sorry to bother, but how do I generate this key? thank you for your help